# How to remove incompatible software flagged during 10.10.3 upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, compatibility

I just updated to 10.10.3 today and got this warning about incompatible software:

[image]

I got the same warning during the 10.10.2 upgrade.

I once had Trim Enabler installed and got a failure during upgrading to Yosemite, so I disabled it rather than deal with the kext signing issue. So I keep getting this message during upgrades, but can't find any info about where this is coming from.

The Qmaster preference is a total mystery, I don't know where that came from. I used to have Logic Pro a few major versions ago, but uninstalled it a while ago, is that the source? How do I locate the source of this warning?

Most importantly, how do I eliminate whatever is causing the warnings? I comprehend that they have not been migrated and just want to get rid of them as I don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Qmaster is the Apple Qmaster.

> Apple Qmaster is a system made by Apple Inc. that provides automated
>   work distribution and processing for high-volume projects....

It is a 32 bit version and the 10.10 does not like it.

I use AppCleaner app to remove apps from my system since it will also find all associated parts of that app.

Comment: Thanks, I've now located the app, having overlooked it since it is named Apple Qmaster and I was looking for the preferences pane. I could uninstall it and hope it solves the problem, but the exact same program exists on my other mac, but it didn't complain during the same upgrade on the same day, so I am concerned that this won't solve the problem. That's why I wanted to know what causes the error. If I can't find out then I might just uninstall it and see if it shows up for the next upgrade.

Comment: To find more details you need to look in the Console log (located in your Utility Folder), there is lots of stuff there but look for Qmaster messages. You can also copy the Pref file from the mac that the Qmaster works.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I see the error: "WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.3 instead of 10.10.3. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number." followed by a trace. However, I can't identify the prefs file from this and a deep search isn't helping, there is nothing with QMaster and prefs. Any ideas?